# Is There a way to parse string response into Selenium Web-driver as PageSource

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Using request response I have received some data from some website.

Since web driver handles many things like running the script present on the page, display only the visible elements etc.

I want to send this response string I received into web driver as page source and read data from it. I don't want to write much for handling the things that web driver itself does for me.

Can it be done?

Thanks and regards